# How to artificially create ConnectionRefusedError?

Tags: web-scraping, error-handling, scrapy, web-crawler, connection-refused

I want to debug ConnectionRefusedError handling in Scrapy. I can't do the debugging without the ability to simulate the error. How can I simulate ConnectionRefusedError?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we can simulate it by trying to scrape a site that is blocked in our country. For example, in Indonesia vimeo.com is blocked, so I scrape it.

It will be easier for China since they block a lot of sites.